# Suppose that $(A,<)$ is a toset and that $A_1$ is dense in $A$. What are the conditions for which $A_2=A\setminus A_1$ is dense in $A$?

Tags: order-theory

> Suppose that $(A,<)$ is a totally ordered set and that $A_1\cap A_2=\emptyset$ and $A_1 \cup A_2=A$, and that $A_1$ is dense in $A$. What are the necessary and sufficient conditions for which $A_2$ is dense in $A$?

---

This question arose when i did an exercise that *$\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R$*.

I would like to ask if this special property holds for a more general setting.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $A_1$ is dense if and only if $A_1$ meets every open interval, clearly the same should be true for $A_2$. It is not hard to verify that this translates to 
"$A_1$ does not contain any open interval".

Indeed, if $A_1$ does not contain any interval, then $A\setminus A_1$ meets every open interval as well.

Comment: Hi @Asaf! I rephrase your answer in my own words: *Suppose that $(A,<)$ is a totally ordered set and that $A_1\cap A_2=\emptyset$ and $A_1 \cup A_2=A$. We have: $A_1$ does not contain any **open** interval $\iff$ $A_1$ does not contain any interval $\implies$ $A_2$ is dense in $A$*. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes. If a set does not contain any interval, its complement is dense.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response :)